# Change background to a vertical line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I try to change a background color to a vertical line when the color change.

So, i have another code and with ta.crossover and ta.crossunder, that works but with this code, don't work.
The error is : An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.

Ok but i need to use integer with the ta.lowest and ta.highest and so not use ta.crossover.

```
indicator('IS V1', overlay = true)
varLo = input.int(title="Fast (Conversion) Line", defval=9, minval=1, maxval=99999)
varHi = input.int(title="Slow (Base) Line", defval=26, minval=1, maxval=99999)
emafreq = input.int(title="Ema on price frequency", defval=2, minval=1, maxval=99999)

a = ta.lowest(varLo)
b = ta.highest(varLo)
c = (a + b ) / 2

d = ta.lowest(varHi)
e = ta.highest(varHi)
f = (d + e) / 2

//g = ((c + f) / 2)[varHi]
//h = ((highest(varHi * 2) + lowest(varHi * 2)) / 2)[varHi]

z = ta.ema(close, emafreq)

bggreen = (z > c and z > f)
bgred = (z < c and z < f)

is_new_green = not bggreen[1] and bggreen
is_new_red = not bgred[1] and bgred

bgcolor(bggreen ? color.green : bgred ? color.red: na)

plot(ta.crossover(bggreen, bgred) ? high * 10 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1)
```

How is it possible then to create a vertical line like the last plot line ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the high/low candle value when a crossover/crossunder happens?

Comment: Hi Daveatt,

Yes because it is the basis of this code. It is a free code on tradingview (i have not create) but I find that the calculation and the logic of this code gives good results.

So yes, High and Low are important.

In fact, I would just like to change each color change to a vertical line or a shape.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing something like this

```
sincecrossover = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(varLo, varHi))
sincecrossunder = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(varLo, varHi))

var float a = 0.
var float b = 0.

if sincecrossover > 0
  a := ta.lowest(sincecrossover)

else if sincecrossunder > 0
  b := ta.highest(sincecrossunder)
```